# How to query a first name and last name string in MySql

Tags: mysql

I'm new to database and querying in MySql. I have a table in my database with id, fistname, middlename and lastname. In my webapp, I have a search box so that I can search my database using the firstname, middlename and lastname and it will display the result in my web app. Do I need to use SELECT statement to do this and what condition should I query?

Please advise.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select id, firstname, middlename, lastname where firstname like '%searchterm%' or middlename like '%searchterm%' or lastname like '%searchterm%'
```

this will give you a very broad result, as it matches on the search term anywhere within any of the name fields.

you can also use 'searchterm%' to match ones starting with the searchteam, and 'searchterm' for an exact match

Comment: if you want only 1 row returned, them put limit 1 on the end of the query

Comment: Thanks. Do I need a special encoding of a space character. Because it gives me no result if I include spaces in my query search like John Bonson?

Comment: you would need to split that into parts "john" and "bronson" and match on both of those parts